# Why am I still seeing the "about" link on Web Apps and Gaming?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, hyperlinks, header

This has been bugging me for some time.

I've got > 2,000 rep on Gaming and Web Apps yet I'm still seeing the "about" link in the header. I've just got 2,000 on UI and the link has disappeared from there, which is consistent with every other site I've got over 2K rep on - and expected behaviour (reference to follow).

[image]

Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or is it [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

*Note: I'm reporting it here as it affects more than one site.*

Comment: Any reference as to why it should disappear at 2k? Shouldn't one get 10k to get it kind of replaced with "tools"?

Comment: @Arjan - I'll have to hunt for it, but on every other site I've got > 2K it's not there.

Comment: Fo me still there on SO 2,530 and MSO 4,277.

Comment: @Arjan - most odd. As I said in the question it just disappeared on UI when I went from 1997 to 2007.

Comment: You *do* have "tools" on User Interface. Still guessing that matters. But then: you have both "mod" and "tools" on Web Applications...

Comment: @Arjan He has tools on Web Apps because he's a moderator :)

Comment: The lingering about while a mod would be another issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations! You have unlocked the 10k tools for User Interface -- except they only require 2k reputation on a SE beta. Notice the "Tools" link, which replace the "About" link for all "10kers".

Stack Overflow, Meta SO, Web Apps and Gaming have higher reputation requirements for the moderation tools, hence you still get the "about" link for these sites.

Comment: Interesting idea, except that I've got the "tools" link on Web Apps because I'm a moderator over there.

Comment: @Chris You may want to file a bug about "tools" and "about" both being served to moderators with less than 10k reputation, then.

Comment: that might be the true issue then. I'll wait until a dev answers to be sure.

Comment: I thought that exact bug has been brought up before (mods seeing both), but I can't find it now; maybe it was never actually posted on meta

Comment: With Programmers going live I've now got the "about" link back on that site. So it does disappear when you hit the rep needed to see the "tools" link, except when you're a moderator when it sticks around for a while.

Answer (score 4):

For non-moderators the "about" link disappears at 5,000 reputation. I no longer see it on Gaming now that I've passed that mark.