# No about link on Stack Overflow in the top bar

Tags: support, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I still seeing the “about” link on Web Apps and Gaming?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72043/why-am-i-still-seeing-the-about-link-on-web-apps-and-gaming)

Why is there no `About` link in the top bar of Stack Overflow?

There **is** one on meta:
[image: metaaaa]

**None** on Stack:
[image: staaaaak]

What is the reason for this?

Comment: I was wondering this myself the other day, but wasn't sufficiently motivated to ask...

Comment: I don't have an about link on the top of my page, it's just main | faq... Maybe it doesn't show for users past a certain reputation?

Comment: It's because you have more than 5,000 rep on Stack Overflow. Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72043/why-am-i-still-seeing-the-about-link-on-web-apps-and-gaming (though the information presented there is incomplete)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have enough rep on meta to hide it yet.

I thought it went away at 10k to make room for the tools link, but now that tools and review share a spot that doesn't make sense. Apparently it goes away at [5k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115058/145982), but I don't know why

Comment: I'd assume just because at 5,000 reputation you should know what Stack Overflow (or Meta) is "about".

Comment: Hmmm that is odd. wonder why they make it go bye bye at that point.