# Was the "About" link removed from Stackoverflow?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I still seeing the “about” link on Web Apps and Gaming?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72043/why-am-i-still-seeing-the-about-link-on-web-apps-and-gaming)

I noticed this maybe a moment ago.

The "about" link is missing...

[image]

...but on Meta, it appears fine.

[image]

[The link to `/about` is still functioning too](http://www.stackoverflow.com/about), so I don't think that this was intentional.

Comment: It went away because you reached 5k, although I'm not entirely sure the original reasons for making it disappear still hold.

Comment: @TimStone: Do you have a link to those original reasons?  Although I suppose they could be inferred...you've been here long enough to not need read what SO is all about, you *know* what it's all about.

Comment: I looked, but unfortunately I couldn't find a good explanation for this specific case. In the general case, you lost links to free up space for new ones as you gained privileges, but you obviously only lose a link in this case now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link is only shown when you have less than 5,000 reputation.